Cookies does not persist in deployment
Cookies does not persist when deployed, it works fine in development. When the user logged in, I will send a cookie into the browser, with an option of http only, same site is true, even tried strict, secure to true, max age into a day. It work’s fine at the very first, I get the cookie and the response fine, but after I refresh the site the cookies are long gone. Can’t find a solution online, almost every stack overflow that encountered the same problem doesn’t have a solution. I am using react with vite build, in the client, and express nodejs in the backend. I am not using a session in the backend.
Can somebody help me with it? This is my first time deploying a site, please take easy on me. Thanks a lot in advance!

Where are you reading the cookies from while testing? The client, server, or both?
Can you perform some additional debugging in your browser's dev tools? For example, you can use the Network tab with the "Doc" filter to look at your initial web request & response in Google Chrome - do you see your cookies in your client's request and response headers? What happens when you refresh the page and re-inspect?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
